# Replacing Values of a two dimensional array in a new method

Tags: java, arrays, random, replace, char

So I have to create a method called populateRandom for one part of my assignment. I currently have a grid that prints an 8 x 8 board and every "cell" contains a '$' at the moment. That is all printed through the drawGrid method I created. For this populate random I have to populate the grid with random chars from one of my chars array. I currently have it so it prints a whole separate grid instead of replacing the current one. How would I go about overwriting the the values that are already there.... Here is my code...  And as of now it just prints only one value from the options array I want my grid to fill with multiple different values (&$*+ etc). Thanks! Hope this was clear enough. PS: Ignore the commented out stuff.
'

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("How to play: type a row and column index, followed by \n" +
                        "the direction to move it: u (up), r (right), d (down), l (left)");     
    char[][] grid = new char[8][8];
    char[] options = {'*','$','@','+','!','&'};
    drawGrid(grid);
    populateRandom(grid,options);
    System.out.println("Enter <row> <column> <direction to move> or q to quit");
    //char randomChar = 66;
    //System.out.println(randomChar);
}

   public static void drawGrid(char[][] grid)
   {
        System.out.println("\t1 \t2 \t3 \t4 \t5 \t6 \t7 \t8");
        System.out.println();
        //Random r = new Random();

        for(int row=0 ; row < grid.length ; row++ )
        {
            System.out.print((row+1)+"");
            for(int column=0 ; column < grid[row].length ; column++)
            {
                System.out.print("\t"+ "$");

            }
                System.out.println();
        }
            System.out.println();
    }

   public static void populateRandom(char[][] grid, char[] options) 
   {

       Random randomGenerator = new Random();
       int randomIndex = randomGenerator.nextInt(5); 

       for(int row=0 ; row < grid.length ; row++ )
        {
           // System.out.print((row+1)+"");
            for(int column=0 ; column < grid[row].length ; column++)
            {
                System.out.print("\t"+ options[randomIndex]);

            }
                System.out.println();
        }
            System.out.println();
    }
```

}

'

Comment: Sounds like a Homework problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the grid array to the index of the random value generated by the random generator in the character array.

```
public static void populateRandom() {
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
      for(int column=0; column < grid[row].length; column++) {
         int randomIndex = randomGenerator.nextInt(5); 
         grid[row][column] = options[randomIndex]);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot! But how do I get it to appear into the grid? Probably simple, I've just been doing calculus all day and I am pretty tired. Would I call that method in the drawGrid method?

Comment: I've been doing calculus all night and I'm pretty tired too, but I think you can just call your draw grid method with this generated char[].

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the values in the two dimensional array when you print it. You just use its indices. You should assign values into the two dimensional array and then use them when you print the grid.